# Why is date different saved to variable different

Tags: google-apps-script

I am storing a date values in two variables, one is a single value  the other is an array.  The first is a string and the other is an array taken from google sheet.  Bottom line is that when saving to a variable one is saving as [Tue Jul 31 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018] and the other is saving as  [Tue Jul 31 06:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018] so when I try to find the first matching date in the array that contains the second example there is not match found.

```
 var cur_date = new Date('7/31/2018') 
 var date_array = 
 sales_sheet.getRange(index,9,last_row_current,1).getValues();
```

I feel like the easiest way to fix this is to force the value in cur_date to  have the 0600 but I can't figure out how to do that.   Any help in getting these values to match would be very much appreciated.

cur_date  = [Tue Jul 31 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018]
date_array = [Tue Jul 31 06:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018](has many values but the first is the one I would expect to be matched)

The first value in the google sheet is 7/3/12018..

Comment: Check to see if your spreadsheet timezone and your script timezone are different.

Comment: getValues always returns a two dimensional array in this case your value is at `date_array[0][0];`

Comment: You're not passing a time to `cur_date`, only a date value, why would it print with time as well?

Comment: @ross that's it.  The constructor is getting '7/31/2018' which is only the date value.

Comment: I changed the time zone and now they are the same however the script does not find the date in the array, when I write out the value in the array the only difference is that it has [] around it, would that make a difference when trying to find a value in an array?

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

Date constructor is not returning date/time, only date.

---

#### Solution:

Format your date correctly for the comparison by passing `new Date()` to method `Utilities.formatDate()`.

---

#### Example:

You are only passing the following:

```
var cur_date = new Date('7/31/2018');
Logger.log(cur_date);
//returns 'Tue Jul 31 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018'
```

To get what you're expecting, you need to pass a time as well:

```
var cur_date = new Date('7/31/2018 06:00:00');
Logger.log(cur_date);
//returns 'Tue Jul 31 06:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018'
```

This is expected behaviour, there's no way the date constructor can print a time if you're not passing one to it in the first place.

So to compare the dates, you can use the date constructor within `Utilities.formatDate()` so that your script can compare the two successfully (with a date you've constructed rather than default current date/time), keep in mind you'll need to pass the time to `new Date()` if you want it to compare that too.

```
var cur_date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),'GMT+1','M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss');
```

---

#### References:

1. [`new Date()`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) for date constructor.
2. [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) for formatting dates in Google Apps Script.